# Image pull fail when creating a pod

Tags: docker, kubectl, minikube

Just testing on local machine. Windows 7 x64, Minikube 1.14, docker toolbox.
`$docker image ls` does show the image I would like to use.

```
REPOSITORY myname/hello-service  
TAG 0.0.6  
IMAGE ID xxxxxxxxxxx
```

In my Pod yaml:

```
spec:
  containers:
  -name: my-pod
   image: myname/hello-service:0.0.6
```

After running `$kubectl create -f pod.yaml`. It failed

```
Error: ImagePullBackOff
Failed to pull image "xxxxx" rpc error: code = ... manifest for myname/hello-service:0.0.6 not found
```

But the previous version :0.0.5 works just fine.
Both image are build on my machine and store in "default" of docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be that `myname/hello-service:0.0.6` is only on your windows host? If so, minikube cannot find it.

You have a few options to access in Minikube. One of them is building your local image with minikube's Docker daemon. Another is running a private local Docker registry.

A few examples for this and more I found are [well described here].(https://www.edureka.co/community/17481/local-docker-image-on-minikube)

Answer (score 1):

Try to push it on DockerHub first

```
docker tag <imageid> <usrDockerHub>/<image_name>:<version>
docker push <usernameDockerHub>/<nome immagine>:<tag>
```

and try again `kubectl create -f pod.yaml`